# Where do the static functions go in ELF binary

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, elf

I made a simple linux kernel module which has a static function. When I use objdump or nm on the .ko file, I cannot see the entry for my static function. Where did it go?

Thanks.

Edit: Adding code

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

int p;
int q;

module_param(p, int, S_IRUGO);
module_param(q, int, S_IRUGO);

static int add(int x, int y)
{
        return x + y;
}

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
        int res;

        res = add(p, q);
        return res;
}

static void __exit hello_cleanup(void)
{
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_cleanup);

MODULE_VERSION("dev");
MODULE_LICENSE("Proprietary");
```

objdump output with non-static function:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <add>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  9 <add+0x9>
   9:   c9                      leaveq
   a:   8d 04 3e                lea    (%rsi,%rdi,1),%eax
   d:   c3                      retq
   e:   90                      nop
   f:   90                      nop

Disassembly of section .init.text:

0000000000000000 <init_module>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 7 <init_module+0x7>
   7:   03 05 00 00 00 00       add    0x0(%rip),%eax        # d <init_module+0xd>
   d:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  10:   c9                      leaveq
  11:   c3                      retq

Disassembly of section .exit.text:

0000000000000000 <cleanup_module>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  9 <cleanup_module+0x9>
   9:   c9                      leaveq
   a:   c3                      retq
```

objdump output with static function:

```
Disassembly of section .init.text:

0000000000000000 <init_module>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 7 <init_module+0x7>
   7:   03 05 00 00 00 00       add    0x0(%rip),%eax        # d <init_module+0xd>
   d:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  10:   c9                      leaveq
  11:   c3                      retq

Disassembly of section .exit.text:

0000000000000000 <cleanup_module>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  9 <cleanup_module+0x9>
   9:   c9                      leaveq
   a:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: Static function can be inlined by the compiler. It is just guess, but without code it is impossible to get precise answer.

Comment: Hi Tsyvarev, I have added the code.

Comment: Yes, with this code the most probable reason of `add` function not being in ELF binary is its inlining into `hello_init` one. You may try to build your module without optimization (`-O1`) or use `noinline` attribute for given function.

Comment: I have pasted the objdump -d output with and without the static declaration. I can't find any inline code.

Comment: Instructions at `1`, `7` in <init_module> are actually inlined addition. As you can see, non-static function usage doesn't prevent inlining, it just provide definition of function's body, whenever this body is used or not.

Comment: Thanks Tsyvarev. I will now try to compile the module with the noinline option compare.